# Aspose.Words conversion throw error in Docker

Tags: c#, aspose.words, skiasharp

I'm working on .NET Core 2.0 app that converts document to PDF, JPEG, PNG in VS 2017 with Docker support.
When I launch app via IIS Express everything works fine, but if I launch app as Docker container in Release mode, then app throws errors.

1. When I convert to PDF:

   `The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKManagedStream' threw an exception.`
2. When I convert to JPEG:

   `The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo' threw an exception.`

How can I resolve that issue? Or it's issue of SkiaSharp or Aspose library?

Comment: We have logged this issue as WORDSNET-16429 in our issue tracking system. We will inform you once there is any update available on it. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Check to see if the libSkiaSharp native library has been copied, and it is the correct CPU architecture.

Comment: Please check [The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKManagedStream' threw an exception](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/287). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem is SkiaSharp, it does not contain native libSkiaSharp.so in it's NuGet package.
https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/288

To work this problem around, I did the following:

1. Download libSkiaSharp.so from here https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/releases/tag/v1.59.3
2. Created NuGet package using the following nuspec

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
   <metadata>
   <id>Aspose.Skia.Linux.Natives</id>
   <version>1.59.3</version>
   <title>Aspose.Skia.Linux.Natives</title>
   <authors>Aspose</authors>
   <owners>Aspose</owners>
   <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
   <description>Contains skia natives for Linux</description>
   <dependencies>
   <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
   <dependency id="SkiaSharp" version="1.59.3" />
   </group>
   </dependencies>
   </metadata>
   <files>
   <file src="C:\Temp\libSkiaSharp.so" target="runtimes\linux-x64\native\libSkiaSharp.so" />
   </files>
   </package>
3. Put the resulting NuGet package into private repository and added reference to it in my .NET Core Web app.
4. Added reference to Aspose.Words NuGet package.
5. Modified Dockerfile:

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0

ARG source

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1

COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]

As you can see I added "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1", since libSkiaSharp.so seems depend on it.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: It doesn't work on Windows for me. I think it's complex solution. I would be very appreciate if you fix that issue with SkiaSharp developers.

Comment: Please share whether you use Windows Docker container. Please create simple application that helps us to reproduce your problem on our end and share it here for testing.

Note that libSkiaSharp.so is still preview and SkiaSharp team is going to add it into SkiaSharp NuGet package once they are certain it work fine.

Comment: https://send.firefox.com/download/4e140c3fbb/#LTAQx2PHPa8k-98-pA-rIg it's my simple application. Launch in VS 2017 as Docker container in Release mode. And to check error you need: execute POST request in Postman "some ip/api/values" and form-data body parameter "inputFile" with ".doc" or ".docx" file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is with respect to the access permission to the `.nuget > packages` on the server machine. I was facing a similar issue on my server machine where permission for the application pool was not given.